Matrix algebra: transpose and inverse of product
In this video about Kalman filters, video here, the lecturer at 42:00 describes the Schwarz inequality as $$Q^\top Q \geq (P^\top Q)^\top(P^\top P)^{-1}(P^\top Q)$$
for nonsingular $P^\top P$ but according to my calculations, using $(AB)^\top = B^\top A^\top, (AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$,  I get $$(P^\top Q)^\top(P^\top P)^{-1}(P^\top Q) = (Q^\top P)(P^{-1}(P^\top)^{-1})(P^\top Q) $$$$=Q^\top Q.$$
Am I missing something here?

$P$ need not be invertible, especially if it is a rectangular matrix.

Wow thanks! Such a minute detail but extremely significant to my whole understanding
